# APK created by Android Studio is larger than APK created by Eclipse. Why?

Tags: android, eclipse, size, apk

I checked the files of the APKs and I found that the one from AS has much more resources included like: images, xmls, ... all related to holo theme. My question is how can I get rid of them? I want in the APK only the resources added by me.

Comment: Upload your project in source form somewhere so that people can examine it and offer suggestions. Or, reproduce the problem in another sample project and upload that in source form somewhere.

Comment: Did you find a workaround for this issue. Please share

Answer (score 0):

Removing from app.iml the following lines will solve my issue.

1. orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="appcompat-v7-20.0.0" level="project"
2. orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="support-annotations-20.0.0" level="project"
3. orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="support-v4-20.0.0" level="project"