# Why are APK's from Android Studio smaller than those from Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, apk

I recently changed from using Eclipse to using Android studio and noticed that the size of compiled APKs is significantly smaller now (1154KB down to 655KB).

Obviously overall this makes very little difference, but I'm curious as to why there is such a big difference.

Comment: Seems some people have different experience http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962707/apk-created-by-android-studio-is-larger-than-apk-created-by-eclipse-why

Comment: The size of the resulting binary might depend on the target version of Android, default build options. Have you had a look at what was inside both apps to see if one did include files not in the other?

Comment: @didierc I've just checked, the target version is correct and hasn't been changed. As far as I can tell there is no difference in what has been included. The only thing that has changed is that with moving to use Android Studio, I am also using Gradle